# tesseract full-on gibberish after clean install

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

1. clean install of tesseract (using the latest windows installer from [here](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki))
2. basic python code

```py
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image


def main():
    image = Image.open("mac.jpg")
    str_response = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
    print(str_response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

3. Enjoy ?

There was in fact no enjoyment at all. I got 100% gibberish - I am not even able to figure out which portion of the image is translated.

This is my input: https://pasteboard.co/4x9jkdjGfQIS.jpg

This is my output: https://pastebin.com/871Wcpc3

Happy to hear what I did wrong here !

Answer (score 0):

OK this is somewhat stupid.

I ran this test on the CLI with

> tesseract.exe .\mac.jpg test -l eng -c tessedit_write_images=1

and noticed that the resulting image was rotated 90 degrees.

So I modified my python script to be

```py
import pytesseract
import deskew
from PIL import Image

def main():
    image = Image.open("mac.jpg")
    image = image. Rotate(-90, expand=True) # this is the only change 
    str_response = pytesseract.image_to_string(image,lang="eng")
    print(str_response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the result is understandable at least (it got the different sections mixed up but that's fair game - need to pre-process to identify the zones first).

Will ask another question on how to deactivate the auto-rotation of images when it's actively making the result worse...